# Building .war file using maven. Missing files and directories

Tags: java, spring, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

I try to build .war file by using maven plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

My project structure looks like:

```
/main/webapp/WEB-INF/
/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/...
/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
/main/webapp/public/...
/main/webapp/resources/...
/main/webapp/views/...
```

After building, my war file contains only WEB-INF and META-INF. All other content of webapp directory is missing (public, resources and views). Furthermore the WEB-INF dir in .war file consists only /classes and /lib directories (/WEB-INF/spring and WEB-INF/web.xml are missig).

How to tell maven to pack all webapp and WEB-INF directory content into war file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch between your configuration of the `maven-war-plugin` and the structure of your project. With `<warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>`, you are configuration the `maven-war-plugin` to look for your webapp sources inside the `WebContent` directory. However, your sources are in `main/webapp`.

I suggest you move all of your webapp sources inside `src/main/webapp` (instead of `main/webapp`) and update the `maven-war-plugin` configuration to:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
         <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

By default, the `maven-war-plugin` will be looking for your webapp sources inside `src/main/webapp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can package your project using Maven by using following command in your command-line.

```
mvn clean package
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Maven layout definition](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html): The webapp folder should be in `src/main/webapp` instead of `main/webapp`.
Alternatively you can also force maven to look in a different directory for your resources. See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Settings

Comment: Please note the slight typo in this answer: the webapp folder should be `src/main/webapp`